# How to save output of az cli to a local database?

Tags: json, mongodb, azure

If I run `az vm list` it will output JSON which I can save to a text file. What if instead I wanted to save it to a database, like MongoDB? How would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple to take JSON and dump it into mongodb.  Azure CLI tends to emit responses as arrays, so to save it to mongodb, use `mongoimport` with the `--jsonArray` argument, e.g.

```js
az vm list > /tmp/z && mongoimport --uri 'mongodb://localhost:37017/someDB' -c someCollection --jsonArray /tmp/z
```